# Parse certain bytes of a variable in bash

Tags: regex, bash

i have a variable that contains the following string (where each dot stands for a non-printable character):

```
.[?1h.=.81..
```

which is this in hex:

```
ESC [   ?   1   h   ESC  =   CR  8   1   CR  LF
1b  5b  3f  31  68  1b   3d  0d  38  31  0d  0a
```

What i want is to isolate the '81'. The number 81 can change, so it can be for example 100 and uses 3 bytes in the string then but the number is always between the two "0x0d".

So the goal is to isolate all bytes (which are always numbers in ascii) between the two "0x0d" and save them as an integer in another variable.

Is this possible with only using bash? Would it be possible to work with regex?

Comment: So you want the 38 and 31 ? Also `.` is not `0d`.

Comment: correct i want the 81 which is currently the string "0x38 0x31" and want to save it as an integer in another variable.the 81 is not a constant value and can change, but the position is always between the two "0x0d"

Comment: Is the other elements in the string going to change? And also, is the number going to be only between two dots, or two or more digits? I can write you regex if you tell me what will change.

Comment: it can happen, but the number i want (in this case 81) is always between the two 0x0d

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte i dont need the hex values.  "1b 5b 3f 31 68 1b 3d 0d  38 31 0d 0a" is just inside a variable and want  to extract the 81 ( decimal) and save it as a decimal integer in another variable

Comment: Isn't the hex value of the string something like "2e 5b 3f 31 68 2e 3d 2e 38 31 2e 2e 0d 0a" How you convert it in hex?

Comment: I think we shouldn't be confused by the dots '.'. Those are often the ASCII representations of non-printable characters.

Comment: @Miglen.com the string in the variable and thus the orginal string is ".[?1h.=.81.." which is represented by the hex values "1b 5b 3f 31 68 1b 3d 0d 38 31 0d 0a"

Comment: @Helyx why are you concerned with hex values if you're dealing with a string? Why not just extract the value you want from the string and save it into a new variable?

Comment: @arco444 because the string doesn't display all characters correctly. thats why i included the hex representation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple Regex would capture the required decimal characters in hex as follows:

```
0[dD](\s*3(\d))*\s*0[dD]
```

Group 2 captures the decimal value, which is the hex value - 30, so only the second character.
Unfortunately only the last group is captured. If you can restrict yourself to a certain number of maximal decimal places you can simply duplicate the term as in

```
0[dD](\s*3(\d))(\s*3(\d))?(\s*3(\d))?\s*0[dD]
```

and replace it by

```
\2\4\6
```

to get the decimal value.

**Edit**

If your input is not hex but an ordinary string, it would look as follows

```
\x0d(\d)*\x0d
```

or with manual repetition (here 3x):

```
\x0d(\d)(\d)?(\d)?\x0d
```

with the same replacement pattern

```
\1\2\3
```

**Edit2**

In sed it should work as follows:

```
sed -n "s/^.*\x0d(\d)(\d)?(\d)?\x0d.*$/\1\2\3/"
```

now with start and end padding `^.*matcher.*$`, and replacement pattern. `s/search/replace/`

Comment: i tried "echo "$output2" | sed -n "\x0d(\d)(\d)?(\d)?\x0d"" and the console says "sed: -e expression #1, char 22: unterminated address regex"  output2 is the variable that contrains the string

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
a=$'\033[?1h\033=\r81\r\n' # or a=$'\x1b[?1h\x1b=\r81\r\n'

[[ $a =~ $'\r'([0-9]+)$'\r' ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

The `$'...'` will interpret escape sequences in a string like `\r`, `\n`, octal representation `\033` or hex representation `\x1b`